# R: How to combine an arbitrary number of functions and parameters into one computation

Tags: r

I am trying to combine vectors of parameters of arbitrary length into one logical computation.  Basically, I am trying to compute:

```
    get("&")(get("&")(sigBuy(">",
               30.30815,
               30.39961),
            sigBuy(">",
               30.39961,
               30.47286)),
            sigBuy(">",
               30.47286,
               30.519))
```

from the following sets of parameters:

```
IndicatorA <- c(30.30815, 30.39961, 30.47286)
IndicatorB <- c(30.39961, 30.47286, 30.519)
BuyConditions <- c(">", ">", ">")
BuySigConditions <- c("&", "&")
```

and function sigBuy():

```
sigBuy <- function(BuyCondition, IndicatorA, IndicatorB) {
    out <- get(get("BuyCondition"))(IndicatorA, IndicatorB)
    return(out)
}
```

The actual logic I am trying to apply in this case is

```
IndicatorA[1] > IndicatorB[1] &
    IndicatorA[2] > IndicatorB[2] &
     IndicatorA[3] > IndicatorB[3]
```

In actual practice, I do not know the length of the parameters IndicatorA, IndicatorB, BuyConditions, or BuySigConditions, other than to constrain that the lengths of IndicatorA, IndicatorB, & BuyConditions are equal, and that length of BuySigConditions is one less than the rest.  Additionally, BuyConditions can be any of <, >, <=, >=, ==, !=, and BuySigConditions can be & or |.  I will be functionalizing the logic such that the user will pass in an arbitrary length of vector parameters (following length constraints above), and my function will construct the computation I am trying to obtain, resulting in this example as:

```
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do.call` and `mapply` can help here.

```
sigBuy <- function(cond, ...) do.call(cond, list(...))
reln <- mapply(sigBuy, BuyConditions, IndicatorA, IndicatorB)

result <- reln[1]
for(i in seq_along(BuySigConditions)) 
  result <- do.call(BuySigConditions[i], list(result, reln[i+1]))
result
```